# Why is one vertex group not a deform group?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am not sure if I am experiencing a bug, or if I am just missing something.
I have a symmetrical mesh which I parented to an armature. After my weight-painting process, the left leg is not deforming as it should. However, the corresponding bone does show the weight in weight paint mode.

[image: promlem seen here]

I compared the deforming vertex groups of the left and right leg. The right leg (green) has a vertex group that is missing on the left leg (red). However, the missing vertex group is there under non-deforming vertex groups.

[image: vertex groups]

Why is the group "Leg_01.L" not working as deformer-group?
The name of the bone is the same as the vertex group. The vertex group is not locked.
I reassigned automatic weights to the bone. I unparented and parented the mesh to the Armature again. It doesn't fix the problem. Am I missing something?

[image: vertex groups]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? (delete the part of the mesh that won't be useful) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Does the Leg_01.L bone have "Deform" enabled?  If not, Moonboots is right, you should share the file for better help.

Comment: Looks like that was it, "Deform" was not enabled. I feel stupid now.
Thanks a lot, @Nathan!